# Replacing ApplicationDbContext in IdentityConfig

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have a problem with context or `ApplicationDbContext`, which was generated by ASP Identity and I replaced it with `IdentityDbContext` in IdentityConfig. While debugging:

```
var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<IdentityDbContext>()));
```

It returns:

> System.ArgumentNullException occurred

Important files:

IdentityDbContext.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using TaskApplication.Models;

namespace TaskApplication.DAL
{
    public class IdentityDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public IdentityDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        public static IdentityDbContext Create()
        {
            return new IdentityDbContext();
        }

    }
}
```

IdentityConfig.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using TaskApplication.Models;

namespace TaskApplication
{
    // Configure the application user manager used in this application. UserManager is defined in ASP.NET Identity and is used by the application.
    public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
            : base(store)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
        {
            var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<IdentityDbContext>()));
            //var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new IdentityDbContext("DefaultConnection")));
            // Configure validation logic for usernames
            manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
            {
                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
                RequireUniqueEmail = true
            };

            // Configure validation logic for passwords
            manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
            {
                RequiredLength = 6,
                RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
                RequireDigit = true,
                RequireLowercase = true,
                RequireUppercase = true,
            };

            // Configure user lockout defaults
            manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
            manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

            // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
            // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
            manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
            {
                MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
            });
            manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
            {
                Subject = "Security Code",
                BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
            });
            manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
            manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
            var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
            if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
            {
                manager.UserTokenProvider = 
                    new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
            }
            return manager;
        }
    }

    // Configure the application sign-in manager which is used in this application.
    public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>
    {
        public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
            : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
        {
        }

        public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);
        }

        public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
        }
    }
}
```

BTW. I was following this [tutorial](https://app.pluralsight.com/player?author=scott-allen&name=aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals-m6-ef6&mode=live&clip=2&course=aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals)

Comment: Please only provide relevant code. Stuff such as ViewModels and the web.config are not relevant for the error at hand. If you get the value of `context.Get<IdentityDbContext>()`, what does it give you?

Comment: I'm not sure how to check it. While debugging, in Autos\Context gives me {Microsoft.Owin.OwinContext}, in Watch 1\`context.Get<IdentityDbContext>()` gives me null value.

Comment: Okey. I solved my problem by myself. I just added to IdentityConfig.cs using with my Db Context folder and I changed `var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<IdentityDbContext>()));` to `var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<DAL.IdentityDbContext>()));`. In previous line code the IdentityDbContext was using wrong class and that's all.

Comment: You should post that as an answer. Next time, do not use names already in use by a referenced package.

Answer (score 0):

*Copied the comment above into a formatted answer...*

*Marcin Krupa:*

Okey. I solved my problem by myself. I just added to IdentityConfig.cs using with my Db Context folder and I changed

```
var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(
    new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<IdentityDbContext>()));
```

to

```
var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(
    new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<DAL.IdentityDbContext>()));
```

In previous line code the IdentityDbContext was using wrong class and that's all.

Comment: `DAL.` , Can you give more useful info ?

Comment: "DAL" was used as a namespace in the code in the question.